# Realizar cambio de valor en una operación al cambiar opción de un select

Tags: javascript, laravel, ajax, base-de-datos

tengo una especie de página de compra en donde se registran los ingresos de los productos a los almacenes:

[image: vista de la página]

La tabla de proveedores tiene un dato llamado `'retencion'` que es el porcentaje de retención que se le tiene que restar al total a pagar, puede ser 0%, 75% o 100%; ahora, necesito que al cambiar la opción del select me traiga la retención y realice el cálculo, pero no lo está haciendo, sino que me coloca un `NaN` que tengo entendido que significa 'not a number'.

Mi controlador `Proveedor` tiene esto:

```
public function get_proveedor_by_id(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $proveedors = Proveedor::findOrFail($request->proveedor_id);
        return response()->json($proveedors);
    }
}
```

Mis funciones:

```
var proveedor_id = $('#proveedor_id');
    proveedor_id.change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('get_proveedor_by_id') }}",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                proveedor_id: proveedor_id.val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#retencion").val(data.retencion);
            }
        });
    });
```

Para calcular totales:

```
function totales() {
        $("#subtotal").html("$ " + subtotalapagar.toFixed(2));
        subtotal_pagar = subtotalapagar;
        $("#subtotal_pagar_html").html("$ " + subtotal_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#subtotal_pagar").val(subtotal_pagar.toFixed(2));

        retencion = $("#retencion").val;

        retencionapagar = subtotal * (retencion / 100);
        $("#retencion").html("$ " + retencionapagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#retencion_pagar_html").html("$ " + retencionapagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#retencion_pagar").val(retencionapagar.toFixed(2));

        impuesto = subtotalapagar * 0.16;
        $("#impuesto").html("$ " + impuesto.toFixed(2));
        impuesto_pagar = impuesto;
        $("#impuesto_pagar_html").html("$ " + impuesto_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#impuesto_pagar").val(impuesto_pagar.toFixed(2));

        $("#total").html("$ " + total.toFixed(2));
        total_pagar = total + impuesto;
        $("#total_pagar_html").html("$ " + total_pagar.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagar").val(total_pagar.toFixed(2));

        tasa = $("#tasabs").val();

        total_pagarbs = tasa * total_pagar;

        $("#totalbs").html("Bs. " + total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagar_htmlbs").html("Bs. " + total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
        $("#total_pagarbs").val(total_pagarbs.toFixed(2));
    }
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿el porcentaje cómo está expresado dentro de la tabla?  ¿como un varchar y terminado en `%` ? ¿o como un número?

Comment: como un numero, sería 0, 75 o 100

Comment: Pues prueba con `parseInt(retencion)` cada vez que tengas que operar con el, a ver si eso lo convierte a número. O ponle `()` al final de esta línea: `retencion = $("#retencion").val;` para que quede así: `retencion = $("#retencion").val();` a ver si va a ser eso.

Comment: le puse los paréntesis pero de igual forma me da NaN

Comment: cuando uso parseInt me deja de realizar la función de agregar los productos a la table, por alguna razón

Comment: o sea, el retención está en la tabla de proveedores dentro de la base de datos; mi intención es traérmelo al seleccionar un proveedor, con el id del mismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inspeccioné la página y resulta que me salía este error: `Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Request] does not exist.`

Entonces lo que hice en mi `PedidoController` fue referenciar:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Que está explicado en [esta página](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests) de la documentación de Laravel y se arregló el error, ya realiza todas las funciones.